# Unable to get retrofit v2 call response

Tags: android, json, callback, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm upgrading retrofit 1.9 to v2.1.0. I want to get the response json and convert it manually but I got something like this:

```
log res retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@41acd528-okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@41ad8a18
```

my code is :

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(Config.baseEndpoint)
            .build();

    ApiService api = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> login = api.login("email", "password");

    login.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "log res "+call.toString()+"-"+response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JsonObject` instead of `ResponseBody`

```
Call<JsonObject> login = api.login("email", "password");

login.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        Log.e(TAG, "log res "+call.toString()+"-"+response.body().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

**Note** : make sure to use `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, not `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: I test it, also we should add `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` to retrofit builder